# React jest testing onSubmit by simulate not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

this is my first week dealing with testing, and i get confused, i'm trying to test SignIn component, i have test the snapshot to ensure that mockup behavior not changing, then i want to test the submit behavior, here is my code:

**signIn-component.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import FormInput from '../form-input/form-input.component';
import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  googleSignInStart,
  emailSignInStart,
} from '../../redux/user/user.actions';
import './sign-in.styles.scss';

export const SignIn = ({ emailSignInStart, googleSignInStart }) => {
  const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = React.useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const { email, password } = userCredentials;

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    emailSignInStart(email, password);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setCredentials({ ...userCredentials, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-in">
      <h2>I already have an account</h2>
      <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          name="email"
          type="email"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={email}
          label="email"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          name="password"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="password"
          required
        />
        <div className="buttons">
          <CustomButton type="submit"> Sign in </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
            type="button"
            onClick={googleSignInStart}
            isGoogleSignIn
          >
            Sign in with Google
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  googleSignInStart: () => dispatch(googleSignInStart()),
  emailSignInStart: (email, password) =>
    dispatch(emailSignInStart({ email, password })),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);
```

**sign.test.js**

```
import { shallow , mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { SignIn } from '../sign-in.component';

describe('Sign In component', () => {

    let wrapper;
    const mockemailSignInStart = jest.fn();
    const mockgoogleSignInStart = jest.fn();
    const mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
          wrapper = shallow(<SignIn 
            emailSignInStart={mockemailSignInStart} 
            googleSignInStart={mockgoogleSignInStart}/>
        );
    });

    it('expect to render signIn component', () => {
        expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('expect call fn on submit', () => {
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
        expect(mockHandleSubmit).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

I have tried mount and render but always expect `toBeCalled` always return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your code:

1) I think this:

```
expect(mockHandleSubmit).toBeCalled();
```

should actually be

```
expect(mockemailSignInStart).toBeCalled();
```

because `handleSubmit` dispatches `emailSignInStart` which you mock with `googleSignInStart`.

2) You should pass some argument to your `simulate('submit')` or the `handleSubmit` will throw an error when calling `event.preventDefault();`. For instance you can just use:

```
wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit", { preventDefault: jest.fn() });
```

Comment: That's correct; thanks, since i'm new in testing, what should i test in react component, i mean what exactly the story or the use case should i care about in test?

Comment: This is very broad, in general you should test critical functions of your application and components; looking at your component, I would test the correct behavior `emailSignInStart`, `googleSignInStart` and `handleChange` (as you started to do)

Answer (score 0):

`enzyme` is deprecated. I used `jest` and `react-testing-library`. The concept should be the same though.

I see that you're passing the mock functions to the Form component. I personally don't like the idea of changing the Form component code by passing a mock or spy function just for testing purpose.

For my form, I come up with this idea (`find the code samples and full answer` [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035248/13607767)) -

- basically I created `handleOnSubmitMock` function, and then assigned it to `screen.getByRole("form", { name: "signup-form" }).onsubmit` GlobalEventHandler. (Not passing the mock function to the Form)
- then I checked if `expect(handleOnSubmitMock).toHaveBeenCalled()` or `expect(handleOnSubmitMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled()` passes.

You should be able to modify the code for your need from the descriptive code samples in the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035248/13607767), and it should work. The goal is to  -

- render the `Form` component.
- get the necessary elements.
- fire the button click event.
- expect `onSubmit` handler to be either called or not called depending on the test conditions.